# Objective-C Indexing

Tags: objective-c, indexing

I'm currently trying to implement some kind of search system in a program of mine, and wanted to use an index, but I'm fairly new at Objective-C. The main idea is to have a 'search' command or text box and when I type a word, it'll show me all the items that include that word. All these 'items' will be listed in a .txt file (hopefully) in alphabetical order. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is supposed to be a small movie 'database' that's stored on a .txt file. I'll program methods for searching, adding and deleting movies, and also for assigning movies to a customer when he/she 'rents' a movie. The only problem I'm having is with indexing every word in a movie title when it's added to be able to search for it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the .txt file into an `NSSet` or some other collection class and you can then search it using something like:

```
[words filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'word'"]];
```

(See the [Predicate Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSpotlightComparison.html) for details).

Answer (score 1):

The ideal thing, if the text file is large and you want to index by the leading characters of each entry, is to create a "dope vector" of sorts, where each entry in the dope vector contains the first few characters of the line, followed by the file offset where the line starts.  Note that one dope vector entry can cover a number of file lines, since it's just serving like the index tabs in a dictionary.

But if you want to search for words *within* a line in your file, you're better off using a SQL database, or some [KWIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_Word_in_Context) scheme.

Comment: I would LOVE to use databases, however, I'm restricted to text files on this one. I like the dope vector idea though

Comment: @iVikD -- Note that there are various KWIC indexing schemes that use a "pre-compiled" data file to index the base data file, expanding on the dope vector approach.  Never dug into it very much, though, other than one relatively special-purpose radix tree implementation.